# Nock is not intercepting the request in my test

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, nock

At the beginning of my test file, I set up my nocks, one of them being:

```
test.before(async () => {
  const baseNock = nock('https://api.stripe.com');
  const productNock = (productId) => {
    return baseNock
      .get(`/v1/products/${productId}`)
      .reply('200', getTestStripeProduct(productId));
  };
```

Then in my test, when I hit my internal API endpoint which calls `api.stripe.com/v1/products/{id}`, it should hit my `productNock`. However, I don't get the value of `getTestStripeProduct(productId)` I'm logging a value inside of that function before the object returns.

What am I missing here? Thanks

Edit:

I've tried moving the declaration of `baseNock` and `productNock` into my test itself with no additional luck

Answer (score 0):

The issue was housing this in the function `const productNock = (productId) => {`

Just having this with a stubbed productId in my `test.before` function got it working.

```
baseNock
  .get(`/v1/products/product_123456`)
  .reply('200', getTestStripeProduct(productId));
```

I hope that helps someone out!